# Replace All with jQuery and HTML5 audio

Tags: jquery

I have a page that loads a dynamic number (however many in the database marked active) of "voting panels" with an image and blurb and an audio clip of artists who are being voted on as favorite. I mashed together some jQuery to "activate" a play button that when clicked starts the correct clip AND is src.replaced with a stop button. When the stop button is clicked, the clip stops and the play button returns. I also managed to get the playing clip to STOP when another play button is clicked so there is only one clip playing at a time.

HOWEVER, what I can't seem to figure out is how to change the stop button back to a play button for a clip that was playing and was interrupted by a different play button.

The site is up as a test but is set to go live with undiscovered artists on Monday so I have to figure this out. You can see my dilemma at http://dev.edrtrust.com/play/index.php/ppm/artist_faceoff.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
  $("img.btnPlay").live('click', function () {
    var thisPID = $(this).attr('name');
    this.src = this.src.replace("<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/playThis.png",
         "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/stopThis.png");
    $(this).removeClass("btnPlay").addClass("btnStop");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('ppm/getVoteClip'); ?>",
        data: {
            id: thisPID
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#clip").empty().html(msg);
            var plyr0 = document.getElementById('faceoffAudio0');
            plyr0.play();
        } // end success
    }); // end ajax
}); // end play button
```

and

```
$("img.btnStop").live('click', function () {
    var plyr0 = document.getElementById('faceoffAudio0');
    plyr0.pause();
    this.src = this.src.replace("<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/stopThis.png", 
         "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/playThis.png");
    $(this).removeClass("btnStop").addClass("btnPlay");
}); // end stop button
```

Comment: It was but when I tried to submit my question, a panel told me I had to indent all lines of code 4 spaces. I will try to edit again.

Comment: I used http://jsbeautifier.org/ to format the code. Highlight, then hit CTRL+K.

Comment: I appreciate that. I promise I will learn better "stack overflow" skills

Comment: What you're trying to do is often done with `div` instead of img.  That way, you specify a `background-image` in your `btnPlay` and `btnStop` classes, then changing the class name takes care of changing the background image.

Comment: but how do I find the other divs on the page to change them before triggering the this to change to stop and play the clip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need one button to say 'stop' at a time, then you can just check for any buttons with the class of `.btnStop` and change those back to play buttons.

```
$("img.btnPlay").live('click', function () {

    // update buttons on other players
    $(".btnStop").each(function(index, element){
        element.src = element.src.replace("<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/stopThis.png",
        "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/playThis.png");
        $(element).removeClass("btnStop").addClass("btnPlay");
    });
    // end update buttons on other players

    var thisPID = $(this).attr('name');
    this.src = this.src.replace("<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/playThis.png",
        "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/stopThis.png");
    $(this).removeClass("btnPlay").addClass("btnStop");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('ppm/getVoteClip'); ?>",
        data: {
            id: thisPID
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#clip").empty().html(msg);
            var plyr0 = document.getElementById('faceoffAudio0');
            plyr0.play();
        } // end success
    }); // end ajax
}); // end play button
```

Comment: I've had to update the answer, because the additional code I added needs to be executed before you change the clicked button - otherwise, you'll undo your current button changes.